# Can Lavabit be suspended again?

Tags: internet, privacy, email, freedom-of-information

From [the about page](https://lavabit.com/about.html):

> In 2013, we suspended service to protect our global customers when the
>   U.S. government ordered us to release our Transport Layer Security
>   private keys. To protect your digital privacy and freedom, we said no.
>
> In 2014, we began development of the Dark Internet Mail Environment
>   —DIME—a revolutionary end-to-end encrypted global standard...

Do they imply that 2013 can't happen again? Are there less risks now (regarding government orders)?

Answer (score 1):

They make no representations about the law or the efficacy of any encryption scheme. The current law authorizing forced-disclosure, [18 USC 2703](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2703), has been [amended](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/PLAW-114publ328/html/PLAW-114publ328.htm), but it is not clear what effect the amendment has on your issue (it is unlikely that Congress eliminated that option). [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/LavabitCourtDocuments.pdf) is the original court order: there is nothing specific to the technology. Whether or not a technology makes it impossible to comply with an order is not a legal question, so you;d have to ask elsewhere about the effectiveness of this change.

Comment: that's the funny thing about stack exchange :) - sometimes people sent you to the other site and there people may send you back. I tried to ask on Information Security and was told to ask on site about the law. I'll ask on meta.

Comment: I'm just saying, we don't know the tech stuff, so only ask on IS about how DIME works, not about the law.

Comment: alright, thanks.